Why is there a white or black border when I import an image?
I'm trying to create a newspaper in Blender. I've already created the image in Illustrator and tried importing it as an image texture. If it's a png, there's a black border. If it's a jpeg, there's a white border. There is no border in my Illustrator file. I also tried extending the newspaper background over the edge of the canvas in Illustrator to ensure there would be no empty space but it makes no difference. There are a handful of images that I've imported into Blender as image textures within this same project and there were no issues. I'm stuck. Please advise.


I don't know how you created the image, but it seems to me as if there is transparency in it in Illustrator. PNG files can store transparency, but if you do not use the Alpha channel of the texture in Blender, the transparent part will be set to 0, i.e. black. JPG files cannot store transparency, so when you are saving the file the transparent part will be replaced with white in the file itself.

I have a hard time understanding what issue you are getting. One thing I've experienced is to change the Expansion (repeat, clip, etc) from the Image Texture node. The more precise you are on your issue, the greater the chance we can help you.

You're exporting from illustrator in the target format right?

@GordonBrinkmann The background of the Illustrator file, whether exported as a PNG or JPEG, is set to have a transparent background. This has never previously been an issue. For some reason, I'm ending up with a border even though my project within Illustrator extends to the edge of the Artboard.

@Lutzi I apologize if I'm not providing enough information about the problem. I'm very new to Blender. I'll take a look at Expansion.

@Jakemoyo Yes, I'm exporting from Illustrator. So far I've tried exporting as a PNG and a JPEG.

Thank you to everyone that responded. I was able to correct the problem by significantly increasing the size of my artwork beyond the canvas edges within Illustrator.
